# How do I subvert this locked uber-secure OSX boot process to do a clean install?

Tags: security

I have inherited a 2017 Macbook Pro running OSX Catalina, previously managed by a major corporation. Now want to clean install and start from scratch. How do I do that? With a bootable USB drive in the slot and the <kbd>Option</kbd> held down, I get a lock icon and a password prompt:

[image: locked login]

I get the same thing with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> has no effect.

Obviously, I don't know this administrator password. How can I blow away everything on this Mac and do a clean install?

Comment: It is possible that the previous corporation installed some Mobile Device Management software. Do you know who the previous owner was? You may need to have them uninstall the software before proceeding.

Comment: That's a firmware password prompt.  It's not coming from the OS and has nothing to do with an administrator login.  If you have proof of ownership, you can submit to Apple and have the firmware lock removed.  Otherwise you need to ask the real owner what the password is.

Answer (score 6):

Apple will typically remove the firmware password as a repair service when you can provide proof of original purchase.

- https://support.apple.com/

Alternatively, you would want the previous owner to send an MDM command or divulge the passcode which [they used to lock the device boot order](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204455). Your best bet may be to seek a legal remedy if you have a right to own and use the hardware while the previous owner hasn’t performed their duty as part of a sale/transfer of your property.

Comment: Ok, to be clear then, *only* Apple itself is able to edit the firmware? (Presumably they have some secret key no one else does?) I live pretty far from an Apple store.

Comment: Anyone can modify the firmware or hire an engineer of course. Distance to a store shouldn’t matter, @Sasgorilla  - Call support or use web support, they likely can arrange all the proof needed to supply you with an unlock key remotely or validate and initiate the process. What apple does is perform an authorized bypass of the restriction as a service to owners just like it performs a service of allowing the owner to lock the boot order.